# umbraco site to jquery mobile app?

Tags: jquery-mobile, umbraco

I have developed an Umbraco site and I am now looking at the possibility of making a mobile app version of the site using jQuery Mobile.

First thought is to start by creating specific mobile Templates for the necessary pages.

How can I then package it up as a mobile app for users to download and install from App Stores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) to package the app. u can download the libraries and set it up do do your own builds or u can submit your html, js, css package to [phonegap build](https://build.phonegap.com/) to get apps for all 6-7 platforms that it supports.